# Block if without end if and Next without for

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim GroupChoice, MEGChoice, StudentName, group1Late, MEG1Late As String

'Making the link variables equal to the cell link for the combo boxes
GroupLink = Range("LateGroup")
MEGlink = Range("LateMEG")
'loop to find which choice the user has picked for their group
If GroupLink = 1 Then
    MsgBox "You have not selected a group", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
Else
If GroupLink = 2 Then
    GroupChoice = "1"
Else
If GroupLink = 3 Then
    GroupChoice = "2"
End If
'loop to find which choice the user has picked for their MEG
If MEGlink = 1 Then
    MsgBox "you have not selected a MEG for the new student", vbOKOnly
Else
If MEGlink = 2 Then
    MEGChoice = "A"
Else
If MEGlink = 3 Then
    MEGChoice = "B"
Else
If MEGlink = 4 Then
    MEGChoice = "C"
Else
If MEGlink = 5 Then
    MEGChoice = "D"
Else
If MEGlink = 6 Then
    MEGChoice = "E"
End If

StudentName = Range("Studentname")
Sheets("unit 1").Select

If GroupChoice = 1 Then
    For row = 1 To 15
        group1Late = "A" & row
        MEG1Late = "AD" & row
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value = "" Then
            Range("group1Late") = StudentName
            Range("MEG1Late") = MEGChoice
        End
    Next
End
End Sub
```

This is for a college project where I need the macro to run through and check for an empty space out of the 15 (this will need to be repeated later) it will then need to input the MEG and Student name into that cell. The problem I'm having is that the `Next` in order to get the `For Loop` to work probably isn't in the right place or something IDK. It's just refusing to work and when I take them out and replace it with `End`, the `End Su`b becomes a `block if without end if` error. Please help.

Comment: Take a look at `select ... case ... end select` syntax for a better way to write multiple `if ... else if ... else if ... end if` statements.

Answer (score 5):

For the `if-without-end` issue, if you use `else if` (two words), *every* `if` needs a corresponding `end if`. You should be using the `elseif` (one word) variant for the way you've coded. See the difference between these two:

```
if a = 1 then          if a = 1 then
    b = 2                  b = 2
else                   elseif a = 2 then 
    if a = 2 then          b = 1
        b = 1          else
    else                   b = 0
        b = 0          end if
    end if
end if
```

For the `next-without-for` issue, you should be using `end if` to close off your `if` statements, not just `end` as you currently have:

```
If GroupChoice = 1 Then
    For row = 1 To 15
       group1Late = "A" & row
       MEG1Late = "AD" & row
       If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value = "" Then
           Range("group1Late") = StudentName
           Range("MEG1Late") = MEGChoice
       End If ' <-- HERE '
    Next
End If        ' <-- AND HERE '
```

`End` on its own is used to stop the program.

I suspect the error is caused by the unbalanced nature of your `for-next` and `if-end if`, VB is seeing them interleave because there's no `end if` so it assumes it comes somewhere *after* the `next`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the logic here a 1..6 is ordinal, just like A..E

```
If MEGlink = 1 Then
    MsgBox "you have not selected a MEG for the new student", vbOKOnly
Else
    MEGChoice = Chr$(63 + MEGlink) '//generate character
End If
```